# Apple using a struct as an enum on their libraries?

Tags: swift, storekit

I've seen some cases of apple defining a struct in their docs but its usage is more akin to an enum. [RenewalState](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/subscriptioninfo/renewalstate) for example. You can do a switch statement on an instance of RenewalState, but its a struct according to the docs. It has the enum's cases as static attributes.

This is confusing to me. Anyone have some insight on what's happening here?

Comment: You can create your own instances of a struct or even new static properties but you can not do that with an enum where you have a set number of alternatives.

Comment: The struct makes it easier to add new values and deprecate older values.

Comment: Apple uses structs with static properties to achieve enum-like behavior. This allows for switch statements and easy comparison while offering the flexibility of additional associated data, which is difficult with traditional enums.